# CSS parallax effect between content blocks

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a series of content blocks divided by a slight translated background. I've trying to take CSS only approach, but all my attempts seem to result in an unwanted bottom margin from the background itself.

Moreover my header and footer are also not fixing correctly as they would when the parallax effect is removed.

The html structure looks like:

```
body
    .wrapper
        .header.abs HEADER
        .container
            .parallax
                .block.solid Block 1 content
                .block
                .block.solid Block 2 content
        .footer.abs FOOTER
```

The parallax effect is generated by the following:

```
.parallax {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.parallax:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url("https://freebackgroundweb.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/pattern8-pattern1.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat; 
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

I haven't worked too much with this specific type of transformation before, so any tips on how to fix it or suggestions to alternate approaches are appreciated!

The full example can be viewed at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qboLKv

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to implement a parallax? Or just get rid of the margin bottom which is not really a margin bottom.

Comment: This is not a margin. It seems to be the combination of "perspective" and "translateZ(-1px)" cause the problem. You might need adjust "perspective" value, "8px" might fit.

Comment: or you can try https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get rid of the "bottom margin" while still retaining the parallax effect between boxes, changing perspective to 8px didn't seem to do much...